# Ruby on Rails : Where i can get error log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in ruby on rails. When ever something is wrong I got this error:

```
Template is missing

Missing template errors/error_404 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. 
Searched in: * "C:/Users/Avi/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/social/app/views" * "C:/RubyonRails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.4/app/views"
```

But the problem is something syntax error or programming error.

Can I get a error log, something like in cakephp?

Comment: where are you running rails server?

Comment: From the directory of your rails app in development: `$ tail -f log/development.log`. This will stream your development log.

Answer (score 11):

like @thomas-klemm already wrote, you can tail the files in log. those logs are named after the environment you are running (development locally, production for live etc).

if you want to get all the output you can do a `tail log/*`

from what i know, cakephp has a really nice application monitoring and administration backend. if you want something similar for rails, you can use better_errors: https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors

Answer (score 3):

Open your rails application. 
You will find a directory named **log**.
Open it then you will find a log file named **development**.
It is the file where are the errors are logged.